# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2016 LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-2.1

I have setup a local Sql Server set up and it's running. I can also connect to it and run queries from within Visual Studio. However, when I make a POSTMAN request to a .net core API which uses this database (both the database and api is on localhost of the same machine) I get the error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Specified LocalDB instance name is invalid.

However, if I try `sqlcmd -s "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB"`, it is working and I'm able to connect.

A bit more information on the set up is below:

Result of the command `sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB` is

```
Name:               mssqllocaldb
Version:            13.1.4001.0
Shared name:
Owner:              MyDomain\My.User
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    9/3/2018 xx:xx:xx xx
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#2690D11D\tsql\query
```

Connection String:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ModelA": "server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ModelA.Test.DB;Trusted_Connection=True;",
    "ModelB": "server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ModelB.Test.DB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

StartUp.cs Config services:

```
services.AddDbContext<ModelAContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ModelA")));
services.AddDbContext<ModelBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ModelB"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Migrations.Project")));
```

Comment: Can you please show us the **connection string** in your ASP.NET Core 2.1 app??

Comment: @marc_s  I added the connection string. I also updated the error message because I had posted the wrong message earlier. Thanks.

Comment: @ravo2Zero,  Can you access LocalDb from SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I didn't try with Management Studio. I tried with Visual Studio Sql tools and I can access the instance and the databases there.

Comment: @bravo2zero Why did you share partial connection string? Share the full connection string with its name as follows: `{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}`

Comment: @TanvirArjel Added the full connection strings. Btw, when I run integration tests using in-memory web servers, they all pass fine. It's only when I try to run the IIS server and make a request via POSTMAN I get this.

Comment: @bravo2zero share your `ConfigureServices()` in  `Startup.cs` code also.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Added the relevant sections.

Comment: @bravo2zero didn't find anything wrong in the code you shared!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `appsettings.json` is the only config that has **ConnectionStrings** section as `appsettings.Development.json` can be overriding it. For the sake of testing I'd try to hardcode it and you can also try a different connection string format like:

```
services.AddDbContext<ModelAContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Database=ModelA.Test.DB"));
```

---

**Edit:** If you want to be able to use environment based connection strings you should always have ever only development connection string in either `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.Development.json` so your production credentials don't leak through source control. You can simplify it by naming it after environment like

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Development": <--your connection string for localhost development-->
},
```

Now if you want to add production connection string for remote database, right click your **ASP.NET Core Website project in Visual Studio > Manage User Secrets**. This will generate and open `secrets.json` file in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\`. There insert your "Production" connection string.

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Production": <!--your connection string for remote server-->
    }
}
```

Then you can load proper connection string by the environment variable.

```
configuration.GetConnectionString(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"))
```

Now if you want to temporarily switch context to production database you can open Package Manager Console and type:

```
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Production"
```

Now only thing left is to set connection string on remote server, because `secrets.json` doesn't publish and connection string is most likely different on remote server anyway. This is done again with environment variable **ConnectionStrings__Production**:

```
Environment="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production" "ConnectionStrings__Production=<--your connection string from remote server to a database-->"
```

Comment: This was it. Had a connection string in `appsettings.json` :( I actually wanted to keep separate connection strings for separate environments. Thank you!

Comment: I have edited the answer to show how to properly use environment variables for separating connection strings.